# the nonzero elements of Z3[i] form an abelian group of order 8 under multiplication. Is it isomorphic to Z8??

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, integral-domain

$\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is an integral domain, so its characteristic is a prime number.

But, in order to prove that it is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_8$, we have to show that $\mathbb{Z}_3[i]$ has an element of order $8$ with respect to multiplication.

Am I proceeding in the right manner?

Comment: That is an approach that will work.

Comment: In case you have not done it yet, the computations are quick, and can be done in one's head. If $5$ elements have order $\le 4$, we are done.

Comment: Can you please give the explanation for this??

Comment: Can you please give the explanation for this?

Comment: In fact, the finite field $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}$ always has a multiplicative group isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{p^n-1}$.  :)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, compute the orders of the $8$ elements. If one has order $8$, you are done.

In fact, you do not need to check them all, since $\mathbb{Z}_8$ has $4$ generators. So checking at most $5$ objects will do the job.

Compute the orders of $1$, $-1$, $i$, $-i$, and  $1+i$. The first four are easy to deal with. They all have order $\le 4$. As to $1+i$, its square is $-i$, and squaring again gives $-1$, so the order is $8$.

Of course we could have checked $1+i$ first!

Comment: I think your first sentence should say "one" :)

Comment: Thank you, I have reworded.

Comment: Thank you so much. I have understood the solution.

Comment: You are welcome. It is likely that not too long from now, you will have the theorem that the multiplicative group of a finite field is cyclic, which gives the efficient solution of Nicky Hekster.

Comment: It seems as though the element 1,-1, i,-i and 1+i were picked from the ring of gaussian integer modulo. But, -1 and -i are not elements in the ring...

Answer (score 2):

Another way of approach $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}[i] \cong \mathbb{F}_3[X]/(X^2+1)\cong \mathbb{F}_9$. And $\mathbb{F}_9^{*}\cong C_8$, a cyclic group of order $8$.

Comment: can you give me hint for first $\cong$